# Удаление элементов из массива STL

Tags: c++, массивы

дан одномерный статический массив из 15 элементов, нужно удалить из него все элементы значение которых превышает 5

```
for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++) 
{ 
    if (arr[i] > sred) 
    { 
        for (j = i; j < lim; j++) 
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; 
        } 
        --lim;
    } else { } 
} 
cout << endl; 
for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++) 
{ 
    cout << arr[i]<<" "; 
}
```

`lim` - кол-во элементов массива, `sred` - число, элементы больше которого должны удаляться

Comment: Это - задание, а не вопрос. Что **вы** делали для его решения (кроме написать вопрос в надежде, что кто-то сделает работу за вас)?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
 {
  if (arr[i] > sred)
  {
   for (j = i; j < lim; j++)
   {
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

   }
   --lim;
   
  }
  else 
  {

  }

 }
 cout << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
 {
  cout << arr[i]<<" ";
 }

//lim - это кол-во элементов массива, а sred - это число, элементы больше которого должны удаляться.

Comment: @Doxid Вставте этот код в тело вопроса и отформатируйте его именно как код (**{}**)

Comment: Уже лучше. Но смотрите - вы нашли, что в `i`-м месте - "плохое" число, и копируете в него соседний элемент (и далее по циклу). Нормально? Да. Но! вы же после этого переходите к элементу `i+1`. А если вы скопировали сейчас очередной плохой элемент? Его же вы уже не проверяете! Скажем, `1 2 6 7 8`. Вы доходите до 6, копируете - получая `1 2 7 8 8`, но переходите далее, к восьмерке. А 7 так и остается... Понятно, где есть сбой?

Comment: `--lim;` внутри цикла считается плохим стилем. Не проще ли будет использовать второй массив куда добавлять все элементы, отвечающие условию?

Comment: @asianirish Почему плохим? Тем более что в данном случае это никак не индекс цикла...

Comment: @Harry ПМСМ все, что запутывает понимание кода - плохой стиль

Comment: @Harry не могу понять как исправить это, чтобы он переставал дальше писать элементы, после того, как скопировал в "плохое число" следующий элемент

Comment: @asianirish в том-то и дело, что по заданию ничерта непонятно можно ли использовать второй массив или нет, поэтому и перестраховываюсь, делая все в одном

Comment: @Doxid вообще, то, что явно не запрещено, то разрешено, но в образовательных целях преподаватели, они такие, могут придраться  ;)

Comment: Очень смущает слово STL в заголовке. Если это слово `было в задании`, то препод. мог иметь в виду применение стандартных алгоритмов. После этого, конечно, задача решается в одну длинную строчку, но по задаче без контекста семинара трудно понять, какого решения от Вас ждут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, вот:

```
int i;
// А есть ли вообще такие элементы?
for(i = 0; i < lim; ++i) if (arr[i] > sred) break;
if (i < lim)  // Если таки есть...
{
    // i - индекс, КУДА писать (очередной)
    // j - ОТКУДА (очередной нормальный, меньше sred
    for(int j = i; ++j < lim; )
        if (arr[j] <= sred)
            arr[i++] = arr[j];
}
lim = i;
```

Пример полной программы: https://ideone.com/LBgRt4

Вот как примерно работает - `i` - индекс, куда мы пишем хороший элемент, а `j` - какой именно элемент пишем. Как только находим хороший - копируем его в конец хороших элементов и идем дальше.

```
Номер:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14      i    j
Элемент:  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   2   3   4   5   6   7   0
Нашли первый: ... 3   4   5   6   7   8   2   3   4   5   6   7   0      5
for(int j = i; ++j < lim; ) if (arr[j] <= sred)                               8
arr[i++] = arr[j];    4   5   2   7   8   2   3   4   5   6   7   0      6
for(int j = i; ++j < lim; ) if (arr[j] <= sred)                               9
arr[i++] = arr[j];    4   5   2   3   8   2   3   4   5   6   7   0      7
for(int j = i; ++j < lim; ) if (arr[j] <= sred)                              10
arr[i++] = arr[j];    4   5   2   3   4   2   3   4   5   6   7   0      8
for(int j = i; ++j < lim; ) if (arr[j] <= sred)                              11
arr[i++] = arr[j];    4   5   2   3   4   5   3   4   5   6   7   0      9
for(int j = i; ++j < lim; ) if (arr[j] <= sred)  (12,13-плохие)              14
arr[i++] = arr[j];    4   5   2   3   4   5   0   4   5   6   7   0     10
Выход из цикла
В массиве - 10 чисел
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все работает. Но я не понимаю что происходит в программе после 24 строки (https://ideone.com/LBgRt4). Стыдно просить, но не могли бы вы объяснить?

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо еще раз

Comment: Смотрите. Лучше чем дописал, вряд ли поясню...

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж у вас указан `STL` то посоветую использовать именно алгоритмы `stl` для улаления элементов из вектора. В частности использовать идиому `remove-erase`:

```cpp
  auto last_iter =
      std::remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int val) { return val > 5; });
  arr.erase(last_iter, arr.end());
```

Благодаря этому проблема решается в две строчки (можно и в одну, но так читабельнее) при этом это позволяет избежать излишних затрат на копирование при удалении из середины массива